# Diretivas AngularJS e compatibilidade

Tags: angularjs

Eu tenho as seguintes dúvidas em relação ao `AngularJS`

As diretivas, eu sou obrigado a cria-las se quero usar um determinado plugin?

Quando é o certo para criá-las?

E sobre compatibilidade com outros plugins, se quero determinado efeito ou ação usando `jQuery`, como tenho que fazer?

E sobre usar outros plugins, por exemplo, `moment` para datas, eu devo sempre criar diretivas?

O `AngularJs` sempre me pareceu bom, mas sempre fiquei na dúvida, se eu quiser usar algo fora dele, é muito trabalhoso.

Comment: sim consegue sim olha aqui no inicio ele diz que funciona com bootstrap https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVAbVboRtGA&index=7&list=PLr6R3Zglau2nXmZHkcl-0pcU1XChEFzZM&spfreload=1

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você consegue utilizar normalmente os dois, como no exemplo abaixo:

Comment: Sempre que possível, disponibilize a resposta como texto, isso permite que a resposta seja pesquisável e sirva para consultas futuras por meio do mecanismo de busca.

Answer (score 0):

> As diretivas, eu sou obrigado a cria-las se quero usar um determinado plugin?

Não. Diretivas servem para que você crie algum elemento em seu projeto, preferencialmente que possa ser reutilizado em outra área sem que tenha dependência de outras áreas da sua aplicação. Exemplo, uma diretiva que converte o texto para caracteres todos minúsculos e sem acentos. Ex.: São Paulo -> sao paulo;

> Quando é o certo para criá-las?

Respondido acima.

> E sobre compatibilidade com outros plugins, se quero determinado efeito ou ação usando jQuery, como tenho que fazer?

Simples, inclua jQuery no projeto e faça como se estivesse trabalhando somente com jQuery. MAS! Uma dica, NUNCA misture AngularJs e jQuery. No começo também enfrentei o mesmo dilema, mas quando aprendi de fato AngularJs, percebi que ele supre bem dizer todas as necessidades de uso do jQuery. Até hoje não houve situação que fosse necessário recorrer ao jQuery. Até mesmo pelo fato de que o próprio AngularJs possui uma mini biblioteca com funções migradas do jQuery. jqLite, [leia mais aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

> E sobre usar outros plugins, por exemplo, moment para datas, eu devo sempre criar diretivas?

Não. Normalmente quando se usa um plugin externo ele já vem modularizado de modo que você deve apenas usar os atributos ou chamar as funções, etc.

> O AngularJs sempre me pareceu bom, mas sempre fiquei na dúvida, se eu quiser usar algo fora dele, é muito trabalhoso.

Na verdade isso é bem simples e mais fácil do que parece, basta você pegar o jeito e vai ver que é super tranquilo.